I want to use alias path in codes, but paths property in tsconfig does't work
Here is my tsconfig:

  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": false,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"],
      "@shared": ["./shared/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

This is the structuer of my project:
.
├── bun.lockb
├── Dist
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
├── shared
├── src
└── tsconfig.json

This line import greet from '@shared/greet' in src/main.ts is reported:
Cannot find module '@shared/greet' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

I don't get it since I already configured baseUrl and paths in tsconfig.json, why tsc failed to locate shared/greet

try '@shared/*' for path key and make sure your path is pointing to the correct dir
